# C#: How can I pass a class to a function in separate dll

Tags: c#, class, dll, class-design, function-parameter

I tried to code my own serialization dll. The code itself works as expected. Now I want to put the entire code into a dll file.

My problem is the following: how do I tell the dll WHICH  class it should serialize?

Example:

```
public class serialize
{
    public static void doSerialization(class serializableClass, string path, string fileName)
    {
        do code here...
    }
}
```

Ok. I used `class serializableClass`, you know? Type + Name. Sure It won't work like this. I was afraid it wouldn't. But how do I do it, though? I want the dll to serialize the class `settings.cs` which is in my main program... I hope the question is clear. Otherwise just ask ;)

Thanks for Your help.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `object` of `class` not `class` it self. Assuming `serializableClass` is a class. Although the library (dll) does not know your class serializableClass. You can make *library* of common classes and add reference of that library in `main` program and library for serialization.

```
public class serialize
{
    public static void doSerialization(serializableClass objSerializableClass , string path, string fileName)
    {
        do code here...
    }
}
```